# SciFi series, one book about some criminal with his extra fat cells in suitcases

Tags: story-identification, books

It was a series, something like Spaceways Patrol or something.  Kind of pulpy, maybe, around the 80s.  Small books, maybe around 150 pages.

One of the books had some guy who was storing his fat outside of his body in cases maybe, and when they were lost (or stolen, or destroyed), he was upset because you only had so much and he couldn't get it back.   I know there is more to that but it has been over 20 years since I've read it and can't remember a lot.  I know some sort of space police were after him for some reason.

There were other books in the series (at least one more), and I don't think this was the first book.  Maybe Interstellar Patrol instead of Spaceways?

Edit:. There is a series of stories collected in a book called Interstellar Patrol by Christopher Anvil, and there is a story called The Nitrocellulose Doormat, but I found that story online and it doesn't seem like what I'm thinking.

Comment: May I enquire *why* he carried around extra fat?

Comment: I wish I remembered more. It has been many years and I can't remember that much.  Just that part was very memorable.  I don't think it was "extra" so much as maybe a part of his body that was maybe disconnected?  I just can't remember.

Comment: Thanks. Anything you can remember will help. Someone will eventually figure it out.

Comment: There is [a series called Spaceways by John Cleve](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44009-spaceways) that runs to about 20 books. But I don't remember anything like the plot you describe.

Comment: The spaceways books are pulpy, short and were written in the 80s, so it seems a plausible match. Can you remember anything else from the book that might confirm it? Do [any of the covers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44009-spaceways) look familiar?

Comment: Might be something interesting to read, but none of the covers look familiar at all.  This might be a lost cause, as I don't remember enough of the books to spark any recollection from anybody.